# How can I filter out a value above 100 so that it doesn't puts it in the sum

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

The program asks for input of the speed, when the speed is above 100 it should not include that value in the calculation of the average speed. How can I do that?

I have put a i--; in the else if where it says else if(speed > 100). It repeats the question, but doesn't remove the value that is bigger than 100.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int i;
    double speed, sum = 0.0;
    float average; 

    for( i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ){ // asks 10 times the printf
        printf("%d Enter speed: ", i);
        scanf("%lf",&speed); // saves the input speed

        sum += speed; // sum = sum + speed; 

        // decides which gear to use
        if (speed == 0){
            printf("gear N\n");
        }else if (speed < 0 ){
            printf("gear R\n");
        }else if(speed <= 10.0){
            printf("gear 1\n");
        }else if (speed <= 30.0){
            printf("gear 2\n");
        }else if (speed <= 60.0){
            printf("gear 3\n");
        }else if (speed <= 80.0){
            printf("gear 4\n");
        }else if (speed <= 100.0){
            printf("gear 5\n");
        }elseif (speed > 100 ){ // when input higher than 100 dont save the input and ask again
            printf("max speed 100 km/h\n");
             i--;  
        }else 
            printf("Error!\n");
    }

    average = sum/i; // average calculation

    printf("average speed = %.2lf km/h", average); // prints out the average

    return(0);
}
```

When I put 200 it should remove the value and ask again. What I'm getting when I put 200 it asks again but uses the 200 to calculate the average.

Comment: What's with the C# language tag? The code is obviously not C#, so I removed it for you. Please don't spam with unrelated tags. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for your problem I suggest you take some time to learn how to debug your code. For this case a good start would be some simple [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and pay close attention to the order in which you do things. Or else use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Just subtract the `speed` from the `sum`.

Comment: @csabinho where do I have to subtract it

Comment: Instead of subtracting the `speed` from `sum` in that case you can also move the `sum += speed` below the large `if` block and add a `continue` after you decremented the index `i`. -- This shows your intention that you only want to add if the speed is validated.

Comment: In my opinion `continue` messes up the flow of a loop. Try to avoid it! Either make a variable where you save if it is correct and add it afterwards or you have to subtract it in the according `else if`.

Comment: @harper When I fil in 10 on every line I get a average of 1 instead of 10km/h

Comment: I promised something different: move `sum += speed;` to the end of the for loop, and use `continue` to reach that line in the case of `speed>100`.

Comment: @csabinho Im so what new to programming so making a variable that saves it is a bit complicated for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can go to work:

```
elseif (speed > 100 ){ // when input higher than 100 dont save the input and ask again
            printf("max speed 100 km/h\n");
            sum-=speed;
             i--;  
        }
```